# Adding a key to a collection in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a strange problem when adding a key to a collection.
Run-time error 13: Type mismatch

Module Code:

```
'comment
Option Explicit
'comment
Sub testChildren()
     'This is in Normal module
    Dim mRoot As cMyClass, mc As cMyClass
    Set mRoot = New cMyClass
    With mRoot
        'add collections
        .Init 100, "john"

        Set mc = New cMyClass
        ' Here I add the key that gives the run-time error 13
        .Children.Add mc.Init(200, "janet"), mc.Key 

        Set mc = New cMyClass
        ' This one also generates run-time error 13 in case the previous adding is disabled
        .Children.Add mc.Init(201, "john"), mc.Key
        ' Generate output
        MsgBox (.Name & " has " & CStr(.Children.Count) & " children named " & _
            .Children(1).Name & " and " & .Children(2).Name)

    End With


End Sub
```

Class Module cMyClass
' This is in Class Modul

```
Option Explicit
Private pKey As Long
Private pName As String
Private pChildren As Collection
'Define Properties
Public Property Get Key() As Long
    Key = pKey
End Property
'comment
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
'comment
Public Property Get Children() As Collection
    Set Children = pChildren
End Property
'comment
Public Property Let Key(p As Long)
    pKey = p
End Property
' Define Methods
Public Function Init(k As Long, sName As String) As cMyClass
    pKey = k
    pName = sName
    Set pChildren = New Collection
    Set Init = Me
End Function
'comment
'comment
```

Comment: wrap `mc.Key` with `Cstr(mc.Key)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have answers to fix your code. But going forward, two things to pay attention:

1. [Run-time error 13: Type mismatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) is a common error produced when target data type differs from your input data type.
2. That [Collection class's key is String datatype,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy13e6ex%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) even though values are numbers.

Comment: The second link is for VB.NET. For VBA check [Visual Basic for Applications Reference to Collection's Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265006%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Comment: Good to know key is string data-type. It is not logical to define a key as string data-type, as keys are used with the purpose of sorting and filtering. Sorting and filtering methods are must faster with numeric data type as character type.

Comment: bonCodigo & @Richie10 - I've benefitted for good from this piece of advice. Thanks to both!! +1

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @vba4all the correct type for a Collection Key is String...

In cMyClass

```
Option Explicit
Private pKey As String
Private pName As String
Private pChildren As Collection
Public myName As String
Public Property Get Key() As String
    Key = pKey
End Property
'comment
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
'comment
Public Property Get Children() As Collection
    Set Children = pChildren
End Property
'comment
Public Property Let Key(p As String)
    pKey = CStr(p)
End Property
' Define Methods
Public Function Init(k As Long, sName As String) As cMyClass
    pKey = CStr(k)
    pName = sName
    Set pChildren = New Collection
    Set Init = Me
End Function
```

Comment: This works, but changes the purpose to limit the input to long only. I need Long -data only to do sorting, filtering etc. Now I need to do additional code avoiding the user is able to input non-numeric characters. With solution pointed out by @vba4all, I do not need to do that, as the data-type stays the same.